# How to join two lstm with dense layer as given in figures?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, lstm

How can I make a network architecture like this ([sketch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ab8Y5.jpg)) in keras?

Comment: What have you tried already and at which point do you get stuck?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, since your sketch and your description of your problem is very vague, all I can give you is a vague answer. Therefore I can just guess specific network details like activation functions or input/output dimensions, adjust them accordingly to your problem.

So generally speaking what you can do in keras is to use the [Functional API](https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/):

```
# adjust dimensions and shapes accordingly
left_input = Input(shape=(100,), name='left_input')
left_x = Embedding(output_dim=512, input_dim=10000, input_length=100)(left_input)
left_lstm_out = LSTM(32)(left_x)
left_output = Dense(16, activation='sigmoid', name='left_output')(left_lstm_out)

# adjust dimensions and shapes accordingly
right_input = Input(shape=(100,), name='right_input')
right_x = Embedding(output_dim=512, input_dim=10000, input_length=100)(right_input)
right_lstm_out = LSTM(32)(right_x)
right_output = Dense(16, activation='sigmoid', name='right_output')(right_lstm_out)

# concatenate or add outputs, you decide
combined_input = keras.layers.concatenate([left_output, right_output])
output = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(combined_input)

model = Model(inputs=[left_input, right_input], outputs=output)
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='binary_crossentropy')
model.fit([left_train_data, right_train_data], train_labels, epochs=50, batch_size=32)
```

For more details regarding the Functional API have a look at the documentation (linked above). Feel free to update your post with more details about your project and we can give you a more precise answer.